# How to get feedback id when a new feedback is created using apex_util.submit_feedback procedure

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am trying to create a feedback using `apex_util.submit_feedback` procedure within APEX application.

```
apex_util.submit_feedback (
p_comment         => :P102_FEEDBACK,
p_type            => :P102_FEEDBACK_TYPE,
p_application_id  => :P102_APPLICATION_ID,
p_page_id         => :P102_PAGE_ID,
p_email           => null);
```

My query is how can I refer to the newly created feedback record?

Is there any out parameter which returns feedback Id?
I have searched on oracle documentation but no info about how to get feedback id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at APEX 4.2 (I don't have 5.0 installed) the feedback table WWV_FLOW_FEEDBACK has a trigger WWV_FLOW_FEEDBACK_T1 that does this:

```
if inserting and :new.id is null then
    :new.id := wwv_flow_id.next_val;
end if;
```

So it **may** be that you can get the ID of the feedback immediately after you call `apex_util.submit_feedback` like this:

```
new_feedback_id := wwv_flow_id.curr_val;
```

However, it is possible that `apex_util.submit_feedback` sets the ID explicitly from some other sequence, in which case the trigger will not set it. It should be easy to test a few times and check.

Bear in mind that even if this does work now, there is no guarantee that Oracle won't change the way it works in a future release of APEX and break your code!

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I will test it. will update later.

Comment: OK, fixed answer.